# You need to display more than 2 hints in the discord bot using slash commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, command

**Question in English**

Hi all. My code is attached below, I want to make the user enter the "/invite" command, it pops up not one argument, but
two. An example will be in the screenshots. I did all this via slash commands in discord.py. Help me how to do it

- What do I have: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e9Zo.png)
- **What do I want** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGK5o.png)

I want to have arguments such as "User", "Passport" so that they are in the prompts, but I have an onda prompt, help me decide

## My code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_choice, create_option

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)
token = "Token"

@slash.slash(name = 'invite', description = '[Отчет о принятии] Принятие человека в семью', options = [{
    "name": "member", 
    "description": "пользователь", 
    "type": 6, 
    "requied": False,
}], guild_ids = [824998118595887165])
async def invite(ctx:SlashContext):
    await ctx.send("World")

client.run(token)
```

Comment: Simply add more arguments in in `async def invite(ctx:SlashContext)` and set `required` to `True`?

Comment: No. I mean that there should be more than two hints and not one "member" hint, you can write the code so that it is like it is attached on the screen below – imgur.com/a/SntJRMu
 This is what I want the arguments to be

Comment: If you do not make the arguments optional, this will work. You set `required` to `False` so it will always be "Optional" and not required...

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the options visible to the slash command user, you have to set `required=True`.

This forces the user to fill in/select the options required.

Whole code:

````
@slash.slash(name = 'invite', description = '[Отчет о принятии] Принятие человека в семью', options = [{
    "name": "member", 
    "description": "пользователь", 
    "type": 6, 
    "requied": True,
},
{
    "name": "member", 
    "description": "пользователь", 
    "type": 6, 
    "requied": True,
},
{
    "name": "member", 
    "description": "пользователь", 
    "type": 6, 
    "requied": True,
}], guild_ids = [824998118595887165])
async def invite(ctx:SlashContext):
    await ctx.send("World")```
````

Comment: No. I mean that there should be more than two hints and not one "member" hint, you can write the code so that it is like it is attached on the screen below